# I want to know how to recognize the NAL unit in a HEVC stream using C programing

Tags: c++

I want to know how to identify the NAL units in a HEVC stream using C or C++ programming. The code should be able to take HEVC stream as input and should produce information about the NAL units such as IDR frames.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *inp = fopen("c:\\test.hevc", "rb");

    // parser state
    bool start = true;

    // current code word
    unsigned long int code_word = 0;

    // iterate through byte stream
    while(true) {
        // read next byte
        int b = fgetc(inp);

        // quit at end of byte stream
        if (b == EOF) { 
            break;
        }

        // track 32-bit code word
        code_word = (code_word | b) << 8;

        // NALU start
        if (code_word == 0x00000100) {
            if (start) {
                // read nalu type
                int type = fgetc(inp);

                // quit at end of byte stream
                if (type == EOF) {
                    break;
                }

                // ignore reserved bit
                type >>= 1;

                if (type == 19 /* IDR */) {
                    printf("NALU type: IDR\n");
                }
                else {
                    printf("NALU type: %d\n", type);
                }
                code_word = 0;
            }
            start = !start;
        }
    }

    fclose(inp);
    return 0;
}
```